# How do I output custom data in a custom post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I made a custom post type in wordpress which takes extra values like $price, for example. I can save them and recall them in the back-end, but how can I display them on my new single-post.php page?

Answer (score 2):

At http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types appears:

> In the form of the single-type-template. In the same way that posts
>   are shown on their own page with single.php, custom post types will
>   use single-{posttype}.php if it's available.
>
> So for the above example, you could create a single-acme_product.php
>   file and the product posts would be shown using that template.

This means that you can create a new single template file with the name of you new custom type and display there the specific data for custom type, example:

single-post_with_price.php